# Converting List<WebElement> to WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, collections, iterator, appium

I am using Appium and I want to print names of the elements in the list.
I am using following code

```
List<WebElement> list = getDriver().findElementsByXPath(getLocator(Locators.MY_ITEM));
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement object : list) {
        String text = object.getText();
        logger.info(text);
        if (!text.isEmpty())
            strings.add(text);
    }
```

But I am getting `text` always as empty.
What is the suggested approach over here.
Note each element is of type `UIACollectionCell` in case of iOS and on Android `//android.widget.TextView[@text='%s']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you should be getting the text from the `text` attribute, replace:

```
String text = object.getText();
```

with:

```
String text = object.getAttribute("text");
```

Comment: Didnot work with "text" attribute, but did give a hint, wherein "name" attribute could be used. So in my case -- `String text = object.getAttribute("name")` was the way to access the name of the element in list